# Array of pointers vs ** : why does one give an error?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create an array of pointers (please don't suggest std::array, etc., there's other things going on). From C I thought the following code was equivalent, and I wanted to use the [] notation because I'm trying to stress that it is an array. I the get the following error, however.

> g++ -c x.C
>
> x.C: In constructor 'more_data::more_data()':
>
> x.C:11: error: incompatible types in assignment of 'data*' to 'data* [0]'

```
class data { int a;int b; };
class more_data {
  public:
    data * bad[];
    data ** good;

   more_data(){
     good = new data * [ 5 ] ;
     bad = new data * [ 5 ] ;
   }
};
```

Comment: which line produces the error? I guess it is the one with `bad= ...` , right?

Comment: yes, the bad line produces the error

Comment: Just as an FYI, `data *[]` and `data **` are indeed equivalent types when declaring parameters in a function parameter list, but I don't think they are anywhere else.

Comment: yeah, that's what I'm gathering. I thinking that's the real answer. Is that C++ treats this differently, and that [] is a bad idea in a declaration

Comment: @cdhowie: They're not "equivalent types" at any time, ever. The symbols of the former are translated to the symbols of the latter, when declaring parameters in a function parameter list. Might seem like a pointless/too-subtle distinction, but I think it's important.

Comment: I'm surprised that the parameter `data * bad[];` is legal at all.

Comment: @QuestionC It's not (g++ allows it in contradiction to the spec). And it's also a field, not a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data *bad[];
```

is a zero-sized array of pointers. Most compilers will reject this code and it is not standard (please correct me if that changed recently). The only use of this construct is an old C-hack to declare variable length structures.

Comment: Flexible array members are part of the C99 standard, so not really a hack. They do need to be the last of the structure's members though.

Comment: Exactly, having one of those in the middle of your object does not make any sense and most likeliy will not compile.

Comment: The relevant spec quote: *"Except
as noted below, if the constant expression is omitted, the type of the identifier of `D` is ... an incomplete object type."* (ISO/IEC 14882 § 8.3.4.1 [dcl.array]) Clang gets this diagnostic right (`error: field has incomplete type 'data *[]'`); g++'s diagnostic is a bit confusing (IMO).

Answer (score 4):

You can't assign arrays. But even before thinking about assigning `bad`, GCC rightly signals "`warning: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array 'bad'`", because your `bad` array has no size.

If you want to document that your pointer points to an array, name it accordingly : `arrFoo`, `fooArr`, `foos`...

Better yet, use `std::vector<data*>` if you can. If you really can't, as always make sure to follow the Rule of Five, and fon't forget to `delete[]`.

Comment: @kdubs [This one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29#Rule_of_5).

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the standard is for an array to have a fixed size at compilation. `data *bad []` creates an array of pointers. You must initialize an array in C++ in the constructor initializer:

```
data * bad [CONST];
more_data: bad() {
    //initialize individual elements
}
```